# How do I send notification via SNS with the number of rows in the results of the 2 Athena queries ran by Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

I currently have 2 Athena queries in AWS Step Functions that are scheduled to run daily by EventBridge. Now I would like to send the number of results (i.e. number of rows) generated by my 2 Athena queries to SNS so that I can receive an email notification daily instead of logging in to check. How can I do this? Not sure how to get the count of the results generated by the 2 queries and send them to SNS.

Comment: What is your attempt?